# extraClasspath - Not working in Jetty 9.4.20.v20190813

Tags: jetty, classloader, jetty-9

Setting **extraClasspath** in context xml is not working in Jetty 9.4.20.v20190813. 404 Not Found - problem accessing the REST call. No jetty logs describing the error.

Here is how I use context xml for mywebapp

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/mywebapp/</Set>
  <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.webapps" default="."/>/mywebapp.war</Set>
  <Call name="setInitParameter">
    <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.precompiled</Arg>
    <Arg>true</Arg>
  </Call>
  <Set name="virtualHosts">
    <Array type="java.lang.String">
      <Item>@sslConnector</Item>
      <Item>@httpConnector</Item>
    </Array>
  </Set>
  <Set name="extraClasspath">
    ../myJar.jar
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

**Note: Previously, we were using Jetty 9.4.9.v20180320 and the above setup was working fine.**

Also, I'm not sure as this problem is because of **extraClasspath**.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the 404 Not Found is because we had configuration to expose mywebapp on multiple connectors (VirtualHosts in context xml) previously but this wasn't reconfigured after Jetty upgrade to 9.4.20. I have reconfigured and it seems to be working fine.